# openmesh EdgeHandle class

Tags: graphics, mesh, modeling, edges, openmesh

So I'm using the OpenMesh library for a project and I'm passed in an EdgeHandle e to a method. Is it possible to see what two faces are joined by this edge? I tried looking online but the documentation for openMesh is very sparse and the stuff for EdgeHandle is even sparser.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the OpenMesh "documentation" is pretty aggravating.  However, from searching for the `face_handle` mentioned by tintin, I found this page hidden in it which gives a large number of useful functions:
http://openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-2.4-Documentation/classOpenMesh_1_1Concepts_1_1KernelT.html

Using the stuff found there, the following works for me:

```
FaceHandle a = mesh.face_handle(mesh.halfedge_handle(e,0));
FaceHandle b = mesh.face_handle(mesh.halfedge_handle(e,1));
```

(Technically, I enclosed the right hand sides in a function call, so I haven't tried this exactly as written.  The right-hand sides should return some form of FaceHandle, at least.)

Comment: Just a side note, this assumes that the original mesh object is also passed as a parameter, or is a global variable.

Comment: Your code assumes that your edge `e` has two incident faces. If it doesn't (i.e. if it is a boundary edge), `mesh.halfedge_handle()` returns an invalid handle causing undefined behavior when passed to `mesh.face_handle()`. So you might want to check `mesh.halfedge_handle(e, i).is_valid()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to deal with this,

```
HalfedgeHandle halfedge_handle(VertexHandle _vh) const {
    return vertex(_vh).halfedge_handle_;
}
```

using this function, you will be able to generate a half edge  handle with the edge_handle. and you can

```
mymesh.face_handle(_hh);
mesh.face_handle(mesh.opposite_halfedge_handle(_hh));
```

to get the two face_handle you need.